# Read the text content in a XML file

Tags: xml, scala

Suppose that I have a XML file like the following:

```
<conf>
  <something>
    blablabla
  </something>
</conf>
```

I want to retrieve the string `blablabla`

I tried with:

```
val data = XML.loadFile("conf.xml")
val st = data \\ "conf" \\ "something"
println(st)
```

but  as output I have got:

```
<something>blablabla</something>
```

The I have added the lines of code:

```
st match {
      case <something>{ txt }</something> => println(txt)
}
```

but I have got a `scala.MatchError`.

What can I try?

Can you provide me some help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call an additional `text` method on the selected `NodeSeq` to extract the *text* subnode within your xml *element*

```
val data = XML.loadFile("conf.xml")
val st = data \\ "conf" \\ "something"
println(st.text)
```

I suggest you also `trim` the result, unless you want some extra space for free...

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you give me some details about that trim ?

Comment: trim removes white spaces around your string

Answer (score 1):

you can consider [Anti-XML](https://github.com/djspiewak/anti-xml), which is a project that was much in favour a while back, but now is a bit unmaintained, so you may have to crosscompile it yourself.

It'll allow you to select the text much better than that.

See some examples:

```
 "parse an elem with text" in {
  fromString("<test>This is a test</test>") mustEqual elem("test", Text("This is a test"))
 }
```

https://github.com/djspiewak/anti-xml/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/codecommit/antixml/XMLSpecs.scala